# Power Apps - Submitting form and stay on same record

Tags: power-automate, powerapp

When I SubmitForm(EditForm1) the record that comes up is the first of all my records.

How can I fix this?

i have tried the below - which seems to work - however if I want to edit a record from my browse gallary screen, it brings up the last submitted records. So either way im not getting the correct record showing!

```
Gallery OnSelect action to include a snapshot variable -  Set(glbCurrentRecord, ThisItem)

Form Item property to: glbCurrentRecord

 OnSuccess action of the form : Set(glbCurrentRecord, Self.LastSubmit)
```

Comment: The `Self.LastSubmit` function to retrieve the last item submitted during the current session. It could be only the first time that the current record is not showing and if you want a better option then  OnSuccess action of the form - `Set(glbCurrentRecord, LookUp(ListName, ID = glbCurrentRecord.ID))`

Comment: I get no record to display using your OnSuccess statement instead of the one I have above.

Comment: I hope you're setting the `glbCurrentRecord` on the Gallery OnSelect by doing `Set(glbCurrentRecord, ThisItem)`. If you're not getting the record using the above statement then you can also try `Set(glbCurrentRecord, LookUp(ListName, ID = BrowseGallery.Selected.ID))`

Comment: Doesnt seem to work =[ , by gallery you mean browse gallery right?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show exactly where you're having problems. It's little bit unclear from the question asked above.